# Cannot factorise this polynomial into irreducibles

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Question is to factorise $x^5+x^2+1$ into irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}$[x].

But I'm fairly sure $x^5+x^2+1$ is already irreducible, but not sure how to prove this as neither Eisenstein's criterion nor showing that it is irreducible mod(p) will work.

The only thing I have so far is to write it as $x^2(x+1)(x^2-x+1)+1$ and show that these are all irreducible, but not sure that that counts.

Comment: I think one way is to first show it has no roots (observe the only possible roots are $\pm 1$). Then we only need to check $x^5 + x^2 + 1 \ne g h$ $\forall g, h \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $\deg g = 3$ and $\deg h = 2$. Now suppose $x^5 + x^2 + 1 = (a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d) (e x^2 + f x + g)$. If we expand that out, we should derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_2$. This implies that it is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$

Comment: Let me add a hint for the OP: The only irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ of degrees 1 and 2 are $x$, $x-1$, $x^2+x+1$ and the OP has already checked the first two. So all the OP has to do is to divide $x^5+x^2+1$ by $x^2+x+1$ and check that the remainder is not $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, both of you! This absolutely did the trick and even better, I understand why it works :)

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $x^5+x^2+1$ is even on the list [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimitivePolynomial.html) of *primitive polynomials* modulo $2$. This has applications in coding theory. Taking the list of irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ and $3$, one checks that no product of them gives $x^5+x^2+1$.